# Using Kubernetes configmap as config server for spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud

Can we use a configmap on Kubernetes as config server. Kind of a central config and do away with config server?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: Yes, this is what we did.**

One thing to note though is that config maps aren't as centralized as the config server.
As the config map is local to your namespace you would have to keep all your environments (test, staging, production) inside the same namespace (which I do not recommend) in order to have a single config in the same manner as the cloud config gives you.

But even if you separate your environments into separate namespaces (which I recommend) and have one config map for each it's still easy to maintain and a good replacement for the config server.

Comment: Thanks Johan. can you please provide any reference for the same if possible ? I am trying to achieve the same

Comment: You can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) how to map ConfigMap values to environment variables for the pod. And [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) how spring boot maps environment variables to properties. Basically you just name the properties in your config map as you would in you application.yaml and map them to the pod and everything works out of the box, no dependencies needed.